# Why is this reasoning for proving that $\mathbb{Z}_4 \not\cong U(8)$ sound or unsound?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Here is my proof that $\mathbb{Z}_4 \not\cong U(8)$.

1. We know that $\mathbb{Z}_4 \cong U(5)$ due to the fact that every element of a cyclic group of prime order is a generator of the group.
2. So what we really need to determine is whether or not $U(8) \cong U(5)$.
3. If $U(8)$ *really were* isomorphic to $U(5)$, then the projection epimorphism $\pi : U(8) \rightarrow U(5)$ st $x \mapsto y$ where $y$ is an element such that $x \equiv y \mod 5$ should preserve group structure.
4. But $\pi(5) = 0$ which obviously means the projection operator isn't even well-defined, let alone preserves group structure.
5. Therefore $\mathbb{Z}_4 \not\cong U(8)$.

I know that the **conclusion** of this argument is correct, because $U(8) \cong V_4 \not\cong \mathbb{Z}_4$. But I am not sure if the **reasoning** that reached this conclusion is sound. Why or why not?

Comment: in step 1., it may be true that $\mathbb Z_4\cong U(5), $ but neither is a cyclic group of prime order

Comment: You seem to be assuming that your isomorphism must be given by the projection epimorphism, but there's no reason this ought to be true; the isomorphism could do just about any random thing. For example, $U(8)$ and $U(12)$ are isomorphic, but there's no particularly meaningful isomorphism between them...

Comment: @Micah that's not what I said. Reread #3. I didn't say $\pi$ would be an isomorphism (it obviously isn't). Rather I said that it should preserve group structure i.e. the order of the elements, the image of any element being inside of the codomain, etc....

Answer (score 0):

Neither $Z_4$ nor $U(5)$ are groups of prime order, so I don't understand your reasoning for step (1). Why not just use the fact that since $3^2 (mod\;8) = 1, 5^2(mod\;8) = 1$, and $7^2(mod\;8) = 1$, then every non-identity element of $U(8)$ has order $2$, but in $Z_4$, $3$ is a non-identity element with order $4$, thus $Z_4$ cannot be isomorphic to $U(8)$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a group of prime order.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: $U(5)$ comes from $\mathbb{Z}_5$.